# How to interpret high loss value from model.evaluate() on test data

Tags: loss-function, model-evaluations, loss

I'm collecting some metrics for my model's performance using:

```
# Evaluate the model on the test data using `evaluate`
print("Evaluate on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_images)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)
```

I have an very high loss in this case:

```
test loss, test acc: [230, 0.769]
```

How do I interpret these results, is it the sum of errors made during the test data evaluation?